# Increment Table Row Script

Tags: javascript

I have this increment row script that allows users to add rows to a table with a 'Add Row' Button. The button adds the row, but from what i see it doesn't assign the new fields a new ID i.e. The first row is FieldName_0, the next row should be FieldName_1 etc.

Then i have code that when submitted goes through each fields and inserts to a table.

Not sure why the fields aren't being assigned the new id. Any help appreciated.

Please note the button works in my program, but in the snippet below it doesnt, hopefully just the code written will be enough.

```js
< script language = "javascript" >
  var counter = 0;
// Start a counter. Yes, at 0
function add_row_desc() {
  counter++;
  // I find it easier to start the incrementing of the counter here.
  var newFields = document.getElementById('newrowdesc').cloneNode(true);
  newFields.id = '';
  newFields.style.display = '';
  var newField = newFields.childNodes;
  for (var i = 0; i < newField.length; i++) {
    var theName = newField[i].name
    if (theName)
      newField[i].name = theName + counter;
    // This will change the 'name' field by adding an auto incrementing number at the end. This is important.
  }
  var insertHere = document.getElementById('newrowdesc');
  // Inside the getElementById brackets is the name of the div class you will use.
  insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields, insertHere);
}

< /script>
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-sm-2">Quantity</th>
      <th class="col-sm-5">Job Description</th>
      <th class="col-sm-2">Total PP</th>
      <th class="col-sm-2">Finished Size</th>
      <th class="col-sm-1"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="rowdesc">
      <td>
        <input name="JobQuantity_0" type="text" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="JobDescription_0" type="text" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="JobTotalPP_0" type="text" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="JobFinSize_0" type="text" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" class="form-control" id="add_row_desc()" onclick="add_row_desc()" value="Add Row" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="newrowdesc" style="display: none;">
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: you have not used counter anywhere

Answer (score 0):

you have not used counter variable anywhere in your code. just update the following line and it should get work.

```
newFields.id = 'FieldName_0' + counter;
```